# Зачем нужен input type="password"?

Tags: html, html5, html-form

Я разумеется понимаю, что в новой версии HTML5 данное поле чётко указывают браузеру что мы в него прописываем именно пароль, и это вроде как, правильно с точки зрения SЕО, но меня интересует именно внутренняя сторона. Почему пароль не прописывать просто в поле `input type="text"`, всё равно ведь сообщение до отправки на сервер не поддается шифрованию, обычно (если это форма регистрации), а так это только визуально скрытое маской поле

Comment: Только внешнее скрытие пароля от посторонних глаз. Ни к чему другому отношения не имеет этот элемент UI.

Comment: А браузеры еще и матерятся, если протокол `http`, в таком поле.

Comment: Вы много видели сайтов что бы было поле пароля text? Если за вами стоит кто-то или вы показываете кому-то новый сайт где есть ваш аккаунт то вы не хотели бы что бы ваш пароль кто-то увидел. Пароль всегда скрывается точками что бы нельзя было прочитать, но некоторые добавляют кнопку "показать пароль" который вот и меняет тип в text что бы проверить его точность на случай надобности. Как сказал первый комментатор - это нужно только что бы его нельзя было легко прочитать. Вполне удобная и легкая в использовании штука.

Comment: ну к дополнению могу сказать что так браузер может запомнить пароль и ввести его за вас.

Comment: @Telion, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy ой да не проблема :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поле ввода типа "password" используется для тайного пользовательского ввода - вместо введёных символов на экране будут видны звёздочки или жирные точки, зависит от ОС и её настроек. В реальности при отправке формы данные будут отправлены как есть, открытым текстом без шифрования, если используется обычный HTTP.

Исторически сложилось так, что это поле часто использовали для ввода паролей для регистрации или входа на сайт. Исходя из этого многие браузеры предлагают всякие фишки при взаимодействии с таким полем:

- Автоматическое запоминание и подстановку паролей,
- Предупреждение о незашифрованном соединении.

Answer (score 3):

Вы много видели сайтов что бы было поле пароля text? Если за вами стоит кто-то или вы показываете кому-то новый сайт где есть ваш аккаунт то вы не хотели бы что бы ваш пароль кто-то увидел. Пароль всегда скрывается точками что бы нельзя было прочитать, но некоторые добавляют кнопку "показать пароль" который вот и меняет тип в text что бы проверить его точность на случай надобности. Как сказал первый комментатор - это нужно только что бы его нельзя было легко прочитать. Вполне удобная и легкая в использовании штука.